# Add offset to jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, thanks for taking the time to read my question. I'm thinking this is quite the simple question for someone that know jQuery/JavaScript better then me.

I have a webpage that shows content when a `div` is in full view of the viewport. But, to me, this is confusing. Because right now, I think, it fades in to late.

I used this piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

Working codepen can be found here [link](https://codepen.io/annalarson/pen/GesqK)

As you can see in the codepen the `div`'s are visible when the appear relatively close to the bottom of the screen. This is what I would like, but right now my `div`'s appear when there probably in the center of the viewport.

I tried adding some offset to the `$(window).height();` by doing this `$(window).height()-900;` but as expected this gave me a syntax error.

Here is the HTML and CSS (nothing to fancy):

```
<div id="container">
    <article id="content_part_one"> 
        <div class="hideme">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                        <h2>Dit is een faketekst</h2>
                            <p>Alles wat hier staat is slechts om een indruk te geven van het grafische effect van tekst op deze plek. Wat u hier leest is een voorbeeldtekst. Deze wordt later vervangen door de uiteindelijke tekst, die nu nog niet bekend is. De faketekst is dus een tekst die eigenlijk nergens over gaat. Het grappige is, dat mensen deze toch vaak lezen. Zelfs als men weet dat het om een faketekst gaat, lezen ze toch door.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>

#content_part_one {min-height:500px;padding-top:90px;margin-bottom:30px;}
#container{min-height:2000px;}
.hideme{opacity:0;}
```

So, the real question is, now do I fadeIn the content when the `div` is just in view (at the bottom) and not when it's already in center view. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your `div` shows when `bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object`. Replace `bottom_of_object` on `top_of_object` like `var top_of_object = $(this).position().top;` and `if( bottom_of_window > top_of_object ){...`

Comment: Your element is always at the top of the screen, so as soon as you scroll of course the bottom of your object will be greater than the bottom of the window. If you push it down below the window it will fade in like you want [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyeOaG).

Comment: @AlexeyG Excellent. That did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code.

`$(window.height()` should be `$(window).height()`